# Class Cast Exception in instantiateItem of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I want to set some TextViews in fragments inside of a ViewPager. i'm setting my TextViews in onActivityCreated function of my fragments when it's instantiate pages . according to some posts returning **POSITION_NONE** in getItemPosition solve my problem but because of deleting all views everytime it's not an efficient way.so i've change it to **instatiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)** but when i returning the view of my Fragments it throws :

```
ClassCastException : android.Widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

here is my instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) function, does anybody know how can i manage this exception? or how can i refresh a TextView in a Fragment inside of a ViewPager?
Thanks in Advance

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position == 3) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projecttracking_detail_customerproject_fragment, null);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
        }
        else if(position == 2) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projecttracking_detail_projectinformation_fragment, null);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
        }


        return view;

    }
```

Comment: You speak about having a `ViewPager` with fragments but you extends the adapter to inflate layouts in the instantiate method?!?! Users will help but please make it easier for them by not using those ridiculous long names(in your previous question).

Comment: @Luksprog: ty for you comment,i've overrided InstantiateItem in FragmentPagerAdapter,as i mentioned before i want to set a textView in a Fragment Inside a ViewPager when i press an item in my ListFragment.the problem is about refreshing the ViewPager.i've tries several ways.Fragments Refreshs well when i return Position_NONE but it's a bit slow , so i've tried InstantiateItem in ViewPager Adapter,But i don't know where i did wrong?

Comment: @Luksprog: if you need more information i can edit my post! and i will appreciate your help.

Comment: @ArashGM Could you elaborate how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fragment based `ViewPager` then you can't override `instantiateItem()` to return a `View` as that returned object will be treated like a `Fragment` later(what the exception is telling you).

I don't fully understand what you want so, if you want to update some of the views(from all of the fragments?) from the fragments then you could use the `POSITION_NONE` option.

You could also just update the current stored fragments from the `ViewPager` and let the other query for data(in the `onCreateView()`) when they get recreated as the user swipes towards them. For a `FragmentPagerAdapter` you could use this to access the current stored visible fragments:

```
PageFragment pf = (PageFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.theIdOfTheViewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
pf.updateViews();
```

you could get the other two stored fragments(one in each side of the visible fragment) by modifying the value returned by `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` with -/+1;. Your fragments will need to be modified so in the `onCreateView()` you test if there is new data and use that.

If you use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` there are also ways of getting the current stored fragments.

Comment: Ty for your help and answer,i'm already return POSITION_NONE (it works fine) but as you know it causes recreating all views, so my fragments transitions got a bit slower.i will try getting active fragments as you mention in Fragmentpageradapter for refreshing just some of my Views.